# Why Arm v7 Virtualization Extension relies on the Security Extension

Tags: arm, hardware, virtualization, hypervisor

this is from the Technical Reference Manual for the ARM Cortex-A15 MPCore Processor:

```
The Virtualization Extensions are an extension to the ARMv7 architecture 
profile that provides a set of hardware features that support virtualizing
the Non-secure state of an ARM VMSAv7 implementation. This supports system
use of a virtual machine monitor, known as the hypervisor, that is responsible
for switching Guest operating systems. The Virtualization Extensions require
implementation of the Security Extensions and the Large Physical Address
Extension (LPAE).
```

I get why the Virtualization Extensions might rely on the LPAE, but I don't get why it also relies on the Security Extension.

Anybody have a clue about this ?

Best,

V.

Comment: How would you protect secure information between guest hosts?

Comment: In practice, I think you should have an hypervisor in Non-secure world, and a secure OS (TEE like) in the Secure world. I don't think it is up to the hypervisor to deal with the Secure world, it is here to run guest hosts, even if there is no Secure world. If guest hosts want to share secure information, they will go through the secure OS.

Comment: I know but I think it becomes a practical necessity to secure information between hosts. I don't think it is a technical dependency, see page 28 at http://www-archive.xenproject.org/files/xensummit_seoul11/nov2/2_XSAsia11_JGoodacre_HW_accelerated_virtualization_in_the_ARM_Cortex_processors.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was thinking the same but the ref man made me wonder if it was a technical dependency or not.